# flink ParserError NUMERIC_VALUE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER

Tags: java, csv, apache-flink

```
DataSet<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, Integer>> text1 = env.readCsvFile("/home/maple/Downloads/2.18.0_rc2/dbgen/lineitem.csv")
            .includeFields("1110000000000000")
            .types(Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class);
```

It's csv file automatically generated by dbgen.There must be a exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.api.common.io.ParseException: Line could not be parsed: '149924|9005|292|6|37|33818.00|0.08|0.02|A|F|1994-12-14|1995-01-16|1994-12-15|TAKE BACK RETURN|RAIL|xcuses across the fina'
ParserError NUMERIC_VALUE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER 
Expect field types: class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Integer 
in file: /home/maple/Downloads/2.18.0_rc2/dbgen/lineitem.csv
```

Why

By the way,could I not write `.includeFields("1110000000000000")`if I only need the first three columns?

Comment: I don't understand the question about using `.includeFields()` to restrict which lines (rows) you are going to process. `.includeFields()` is used to specify the fields (columns), not rows.

Comment: I tried it,I really dont need to write `.includeFields("1110000000000000")`if I only need the first three columns.

Answer (score 0):

`evn.readCsvFile()` returns a [`CsvReader`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/io/CsvReader.html). I'm assuming the exception is because you didn't set the delimiter string to be `"|"`, and the default delimiter is `","`.

Comment: `","`is right,thanks.Other people tells me `"|"` can also be used,I dont know whats wrong

Comment: The error says `"Line could not be parsed: '149924|9005|292|6|37|33818.00|0.08|0.02|A|F|1994-12-14|1995-01-16|1994-12-15|TAKE BACK RETURN|RAIL|xcuses across the fina..."`, right? So that means your file is using the `|` character as its delimiter.